# Does R data.table have similar functions as formatRound in DT package?

Tags: r, format, data.table

DT.formatRound apply CSS styles, and uses datatable functions.
Does data.table package have something similar for formating numbers

Comment: `data.table` package is entirely unrelated. It's a backend improvement to data frames and does not handle formatting.

Comment: thanks for your comment. just curious, how would you do formatting with a data.table/ data.frame?

Comment: To what output? Shiny, console, markdown? DT is a front end package, data.table is backend. Consider using DT to display your data.table

Comment: need to output to excel.

Comment: you can format columns in data.table with `format` function, or any other function that turns your columns into character fields